# Collectors.toUnmodifiableList vs Collections.unmodifiableList in Java 10

Tags: java, java-8, java-10

As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) the method `Collections.unmodifiableList` returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. Is the list returned truly unmodifiable? What do we mean by unmodifiable view?

As per [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableList()) the method `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList` returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into an unmodifiable List in encounter order. Is the list returned here truly unmodifiable?

Note: By modifiable I mean the view can be modified by using `set` operation. I want to understand the difference and how are they related?

Comment: Did you not use google? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#unmodview

Comment: Do you perhaps have a special definition of `unmodifiable`? If not, have you tried operations like `add`, `addAll`, `remove`, etc on those lists?

Comment: I believe by unmodifiable she means `set` operation on underlying collection which changes the unmodifiable view as well.

Comment: I am not sure why do we discourage newbies from asking questions by down voting. We should have some patience.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650701/why-can-we-change-the-unmodifiable-list-if-we-have-the-original-one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method `Collections.unmodifiableList` returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. An unmodifiable view collection is a collection that is unmodifiable and is also a view onto a backing collection. Note that changes to the backing collection might still be 
possible, and if they occur, they are visible through the unmodifiable view.

```
List<String> srcList = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry");
var fruits = new ArrayList<>(srcList);
var unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(fruits);     
fruits.set(0, "Apricot");
var modFruit = unmodifiableList.get(0);
System.out.println(modFruit); // prints Apricot
```

We can have a true immutable list in **Java 10** and later. There are two ways to get **truly unmodifiable list** as shown below:

1. `var unmodifiableList = List.copyOf(srcList);`   => prints Apple
2. `var unmodifiableList = srcList.stream().collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());`    => prints Apple

So the method `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList` returns a true unmodifiable list `List.of` introduced in Java 9. This method returns a `Collector` where as the method `Collections.unmodifiableList` returns a list. As per [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) the unmodifiable lists has following characteristics:

> 1. They are unmodifiable. Elements cannot be added, removed, or replaced. Calling any mutator method on the List will always cause
>      `UnsupportedOperationException` to be thrown. However, if the contained
>      elements are themselves mutable, this may cause the List's contents to
>      appear to change.
> 2. They disallow null elements. Attempts to create them with null elements result in `NullPointerException`.
> 3. They are serializable if all elements are serializable.
> 4. The order of elements in the list is the same as the order of the provided arguments, or of the elements in the provided array.
> 5. They are `value-based`. Callers should make no assumptions about the identity of the returned instances. Factories are free to create new
>      instances or reuse existing ones. Therefore, identity-sensitive
>      operations on these instances (reference equality (==), identity hash
>      code, and synchronization) are unreliable and should be avoided.
> 6. They are serialized as specified on the Serialized Form page.

Answer (score 4):

`Collections.unmodifiableList` returns an `unmodifiable view`, which means calling any methods of the returned `List` that mutate the `List` would throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. However, the original `List` that was passed to that method can still be modified (assuming it is modifiable), and such modifications will be reflected in the `List` returned by `Collections.unmodifiableList`. Therefore, it can only be considered "truly unmodifiable" if you don't have access to the original `List`.

`Collectors.toUnmodifiableList`, on the other hand, is used to generate a new `List` which is unmodifiable, so there is no way to modify that `List`. Therefore it is "truly unmodifiable".

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList` just uses the implementation of `List::of` that was added in java-9, the finisher for that implementation is:

```
list -> (List<T>)List.of(list.toArray()
```

where `list` is just an `ArrayList`; so your question just boils down to what is the difference between `List::of` and `Collections::unmodifiableList` (of course with the caveat that this is not specified and happens *under the current implementation*) and while I could detail some of the differences, [there are already good ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39395257/1059372) (and many more if you search).

One point to note is how these different types handle `null`s (the other point that one s actually a *view*, was already provided in the other answers):

```
List<Integer> left = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    Collections::unmodifiableList));

    System.out.println(left.contains(null));

    List<Integer> right = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());

    System.out.println(right.contains(null));
```

The last line of code will throw an Exception, you might not expect that at all.